# Hello, I deployed the war file but I can't start it

Tags: tomcat, gradle, deployment

The error is: 
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: Someone knows how can I solve this problem?Thank you in advance

Comment: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747) ~[spring-beans-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error.

If you want to know which JAR files are being scanned unnecessarily (which only wastes startup time), follow the instructions you see in the log.

Comment: FAIL - Application at context path /fineract-provider could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fineract-provider]]

                                                                                                                 
                                                                          I am getting this one too

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question on SO instead of adding your new question as a comment to an answer.